# Custom event for wpf UIElement

Tags: wpf, events, uielement

Is is possible to fire event when a `UIElement`'s location is changed in wpf? We can fire location changed event in case of Windows but can we have a custom event which fires when a `UIElement`'s location is changed in the Window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2009/12/21/wpf-manipulation-basics/) will help you, `UIElement` supports a lot of Events. I think what you are looking for are Manipulation Events or the `LayoutUpdate` Event.

[MSDN UIElement Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for the general case. The `UIElement` doesn't even know the location it's rendered to.

You can do it for particular cases, though. You can use events of the layout parent, like the `Left` and `Top` attached property of the `Canvas`, the scroll offset of a `ScrollViewer`, etc., depending on where your `UIElement` is in the visual tree.